# How do i get a particular day from Jan to Dec

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am trying to get all the 7th day in the year 2009. 
I am a bit confused about how to go about it. Below is my code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO MY CALENDER CLASS");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(DAY_OF_MONTH,7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2009);

        for(int i =1; i <= 12; i++){
            calendar.set(DAY_OF_MONTH,i);
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Update: This below is my result

```
Sun Mar 01 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Mon Mar 02 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Tue Mar 03 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Wed Mar 04 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Thu Mar 05 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Fri Mar 06 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Sat Mar 07 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Sun Mar 08 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Mon Mar 09 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Tue Mar 10 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Wed Mar 11 23:41:14 GMT 2009 
Thu Mar 12 23:41:14 GMT 2009
```

Comment: what Java version do you use?

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve and why the code you have provided doesn't work the way you expected. Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see where it departs from your expected results?

Comment: Java version 11.02 @LaksithaRanasingha

Comment: I want to get all the 7th day in the year 2009 @Jason

Comment: @EdemRobin we know you want to get all the 7th in 2009. You can also try to describle the result from your current code.

Comment: @EdemRobin Do you mean "every 7th day in the year" or "the 7th day of each month in the year"?

Comment: In the loop you set the `DAY_OF_MONTH` instead of the `MONTH` (which starts with 0, by the way).

Comment: the 7th day of each month in the year @MadProgrammer

Comment: @howie This below is my result
Sun Mar 01 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Mon Mar 02 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Tue Mar 03 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Wed Mar 04 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Thu Mar 05 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Fri Mar 06 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Sat Mar 07 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Sun Mar 08 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Mon Mar 09 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Tue Mar 10 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Wed Mar 11 23:41:14 GMT 2009
Thu Mar 12 23:41:14 GMT 2009

Comment: So you wnat Jan 07 , Feb 07....Dec 07 ?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher  for pointing out my error. I change DAT_OF_MONTH to MONTH and it works.

Answer (score 2):

OK, assuming you are starting from 1st of January here is a simple example for your cause. I hope Java1.8 code is clear to you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create two localdate start of a year instances, one for current year and one for next year, 2009 and 2010 respectively
        LocalDate thisYear = LocalDate.of(2009, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        LocalDate nextYear = LocalDate.of(2010, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        // used only for counting number of every seventh day in a year
        int i=0;
        // while we are not in the next year, 2010
        while (thisYear.isBefore(nextYear)) {
            i++;
            // print current date
            System.out.println(i+" " + thisYear.toString());
            // add a week or seven days to our thisYear instance and loop thru again
            thisYear = thisYear.plusWeeks(1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that in the `for` loop you set the day and not the month for the `Calendar` object.
So change to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
}
```

The loop starts from 0 and goes up to 11 because the months are 0 based.
If you can use `LocalDate` then your code would be much simpler and more efficient:

```
System.out.println("WELCOME TO MY CALENDER CLASS");

LocalDate date;
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
    date = LocalDate.of(2009, Month.of(i), 7);
    System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)));
}
```